# How to read a message from MQ using Java

Tags: java, compilation, queue, mq

I am very new to Java and require some help.
I am looking to read a message from an MQ queue, then output the message to a txt file and finally delete the original message from the queue.
I have came up with the following, but it won't compile.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

```
public class test
{
public static void main(String[] args);
{
MQQueueManager QMgr=new MQQueueManager(qManager);                   
int openOptions=MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_BROWSE;
MQQueue queue=QMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);         
MQMessage theMessage=new MQMessage();
MQGetMessageOptions gmo=new MQGetMessageOptions();  

gmo.options=MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
gmo.matchOptions=MQC.MQMO_NONE;
gmo.waitInterval=5000;

boolean thereAreMessages=true;

while(thereAreMessages){             **(Gives an "Illegal start of type" error)**
try{
    queue.get(theMessage,gmo);
    String msgText = theMessage.readString(theMessage.getMessageLength());
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new         FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\js04279\\Desktop\\test.txt")):
System.setOut(out);

System.out.println("REMOVING.............................");
getMessageOptions.options =MQC.MQGMO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR;
}

catch(MQException e){
    if(e.reasonCode == e.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) 
        System.out.println("No more message available or retrieved");
        thereAreMessages=false;
    } 

catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("ERROR: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}

I got the following error messages:
"test.java:17: illegal start of type"      - this was at the while statement
"test.java:35: <identifier> expected"
```

Comment: Do you receive an error message?

Comment: Yes I get an error message saying: "test.java:17: illegal start of type" for the While statement and another error of "test.java:35: <identifier> expected"

Comment: There are some syntax errors. Unless you enjoy manually compiling java source and getting bogged down in interpreting compiler errors, I suggest you use an IDE that does all of this and much more for you. [Eclipse is hugely popular, highly extendable, and free.](https://www.eclipse.org/home/index.php)

Comment: Can you tell me the jar file name, and where I can able to download.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all you have in the class, then I think you are missing 2 closing brace. 1 for the main method and 1 for the class.

I see your last closing brace is for the while loop.

Java will consider this as the closing brace for the class and will interpret as if you are writing statements at the class level. This is not allowed and thus treated as Illegal start of type.

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon after Public static void main(String args[]);

The correct statement is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   //TODO your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use an IDE like Eclipse or Net Beans in order to avoid compile time errors. Using IDE will help you in many other ways.

Your code seems fine to me. There is really no need to delete a message from the queue. It should be automatically deleted once the message is read from the queue.